# Critical and regular values of height functions on a closed hypersurface

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be a closed connected hypersurface of $n$-dimensional in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}=\{(x^1,\cdots,x^{n+1})\}$ and let $\nu$ be a smooth unit normal vector field of $M$ at $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, $H$ be the mean curvature of $M$ in direction $\nu$. Let $q\in M$ be a maximum point of the height function $x^{n+1}$. i.e. $x^{n+1}(q)=\displaystyle\max_{p\in M}x^{n+1}(p)=:t_0$.

Then does it hold that

> $\exists\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $t_0-\varepsilon<t<t_0$ $\Rightarrow$ $t$
>   is a regular value of the height function $x^{n+1}$

under the condition that *$H\neq0$ at each point*? How to prove it?

I don't know whether the condition $H\neq0$ is necessary.

**NOTE** Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set and $f\in C^\infty(\Omega)$. Then the mean curvature $H$ of its graph $M:=\{(x,f(x))\in\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\vert x\in \Omega\}$ is
\begin{eqnarray}
H(x,f(x))=\dfrac{\Delta f(x)}{\sqrt{1+|\nabla f(x)|^2}}-\dfrac{ ^t\nabla f(x)\mathrm{Hess}f(x)\nabla f(x)}{(1+|\nabla f(x)|^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray}
when the unit normal is taken upward. Here the Laplacian, $\nabla$ and Hessian are taken in $\Omega$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the case $n=1$, the condition $H \neq 0$ is not strong enough to guarantee that the height function is (at least in a neighborhood of the 'maximal locus' $N := (x^{n+1})^{-1}(t_0) \cap M$) a [Morse-Bott function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse.E2.80.93Bott_theory), which is a sufficient condition (by the [Morse(-Bott) lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma)) to get the sought-after result.

Indeed, your question is of a local nature, so you only need to restrict your attention to a neighborhood $V$ of $N$. Of course, you can choose this neighbordhood small enough so that $V$ is the graph of a height function $f$. At any point of $p \in N$, $\nabla f = 0$, so that

$$ H(p) = \left(\Delta f \right)(p) \neq 0 \, .$$

Since $\Delta f$ is the trace of the Hessian matrix, we conclude that the curvature in at least one direction is different from 0. However, if $n > 1$, it does not imply that the Hessian is non-degenerate in sufficiently many normal directions to $N$ in $M$ (and not even that $N$ is a submanifold to $M$, which is a necessary condition to speak of a normal direction to $N$...).

This leaves *a priori* the possibility that a sequence of critical points approaches $N$ along a direction where the Hessian is degenerate. In fact, a counter-example can be obtained along these lines.

For instance, consider the function $f : (0,1) \to (0, 1]$ defined as

$$ f(t) = 1 + \int_0^{t} \rho(s) \frac{d}{ds}\left( \sqrt{1-s^2} \right) ds$$

where $\rho(s) = e^{1- \frac{1}{s^2}} \, \left( \sin \frac{\pi}{2s}  \right)^2$. It looks kind of like $t \mapsto \sqrt{1-t^2}$, except that it has an infinite number of critical points near $t=0$ and $|f''|$ is quite small near $t=0$. With the help of (two 'translated copies' of) $f$, we can embed a distorted  circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centred at the origin and then use this circle to embed a distorted sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a surface of revolution (around an axis different from $x^3$). It is rather clear that $H \neq 0$ (at least in a neighborhood of $N$, which is only a point). The height function is not Morse(-Bott), since the Hessian is degenerate in one of the two directions normal to $N$ and indeed, the critical values cumulate at $t_0$. Incidentally, this shows that the Morse-Bott condition is not a superfluous one in order to guarantee the 'isolation' of the critical loci.